# mysql select record with an escaped quote

Tags: php, mysql, quotes, mysql-real-escape-string

I have a function where users can pull a record searching by a text field. The input is put into the following SQL query:

```
$db->query("Select * from users where name = '".$db->real_escape_string($posted_var)."' limit 1");
```

$db is a mysqli connection object

Works perfect until I have a ' in the name.. then the user is required to manually escape the quote to get it to match........ Shouldn't the real_escape_string() function do that for me?

I have a test record where name is "test\'string" in the database.

```
$posted_var = "test'string"; // no match 
$posted_var = "test\'string"; // match
```

Anyone have any idea why real_escape_string() wouldn't add the backslashes?

The MySQL server and this particular table are both utf8_unicode_ci. I don't know what else could cause this....

Thanks for reading!

Comment: You likely have stored an escaped quote in the database by encoding it twice initially. And since you seem unaware of which context which escaping pertains to, it might be advisable to read up on prepared statements / bound values to forgo it altogether.

Comment: All that I am unaware of is what your comment means.... "since you seem unaware of which context which escaping pertains to"?? The string is inserted with real_escap_string, and then I am trying to select it back with real_escape_sting... why would it encode it twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `\` is literally inside the text in the db record, then you need

```
$sql = "SELECT .... name='foo\\bar'";
                             ^^---double escaped
```

The first `\` will be stripped off by the DB's sql parser. Then the remaining `foo\bar` will be used for the field searches.

---

comment followup: You're not understanding the purpose of escaping:

```
$name = "Miles O'Brien";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE name='" . $db->real_escape_string($name) . "';";
```

This will produce:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE name='Miles O\'Brien';
```

and that's what literally gets send to the DB engine. When the SQL parser gets hold of it, that first `\` escape is removed, and the DB will be looking for `Miles O'Brien` in the `name` field - note that the backslash is no longer there.

Since your DB record literally is contains `Miles O\'Brien`, **WITH** the `\` embedded in the record, you need to double escape, so the query becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE name='Miles O\\'Brien';
```

Same thing happens: The SQL parser removes the first layer of escaping, and the DB will now be searching for `Miles O\'Brien`.

Comment: Then escape the test twice `mysql_real_escape_string(mysql_real_escape_string($foo))`. If you're **NOT** doing that already, then you're wide open to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: I am inserting through mysqli_real_escape_string() once... why would I need to escape it twice on the way out?

Comment: I originally thought that.. I am inserting through mysqli_real_escape_string() once.... and I have always ended up with the \ in my record, so I assumed it was a change in procedure when I switched form mysql to mysqli a few years ago.  It appears that is the real problem then. Why would mysqli_real_escape_string add the slash to the data in the field????

Comment: if you get get a ``\`` in the db and you only escaped once, then your php probably has magic_quotes enabled, which means it's either horribly configured or badly out of date, or both.

Comment: That was my thought exactly.. but no.. 5.4.4-14+deb7u7. I am doing some testing now.. and it appears to be something to do with the WordPress install I've been using. In the header, there are no problems... after the Wordpress core loads.. there are quotes in my _REQUEST object. It appears this is entirely the problem... thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Yeah.. and as of now.. I feel the same way. I re-wrote this app as a wordpress plugin 3 years ago for a client.. and that's when I changed to mysqli. Turns out my symptom was coincidental... this is a BLUNDER in the wordpress core https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18322 Thanks again for helping me sort this out.