# Mysqli string comparison failing due to backslashe in quotes

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query like this :

```
SELECT p.PRO_Id 
FROM projects p, developer d 
WHERE p.PRO_Name = 'Navin Enclave\'s' 
  AND d.DEV_Name = 'Navin\'s group of Companies' 
  AND p.DEV_Id=d.DEV_Id 
LIMIT 1
```

which is suppose to fetch a project name **'Navin Enclave\'s'** and there developer.

The mysql db value is stored like **'Navin Enclave\'s'** properly escaped the quotes.

But I am not able to get the expected result.

My mysqli wrapper class is:https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class

Comment: what i found out is $db->escape methods escapes those strings with quotes with backslashes like \'. but i why the comparison is failing, thats plum.

Comment: i typically use `LIKE` comparison for strings. While not an answer to your question, it might still solve your problem?

Comment: Why does your database content contain backslash escaped quotes?! That is ***not*** "proper". You're screwing up your escaping somewhere badly.

Comment: i had used both like p.PRO_Name='Navin's' , p.PRO_Name ='Navin\'s'. But both are resulting empty results found.

Comment: im escaping quotes for protection against sql injection. Isn't that right deceze.

Comment: similar problem here: See this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23588294/mysql-select-record-with-an-escaped-quote

Comment: Read this first: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: hahaha good plug, @deceze ;) :D

Comment: I got the answer. just put a addslashes before the variable and then search for 'Navin Encalve\'s'. so this becomes 'Navin Encalve\\'s' and php doesn't escape quote.

Comment: Well, yes, if you need a literal backslash you need to double it... but that's missing the point: **you're not supposed to have backslashes in your database in the first place!** Your database contains garbage data. Fix *that* problem first!

Comment: Is it. but if there is single quotes or double quotes in the user input. then how can i escape it. if not escaped, isn't the query prone to sql injection.  I tried with mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $name), $db->escape($name), addslashes($name). But all of them is adding slashes where the quotes are. Oh im confused, could you suggest me a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
SELECT p.PRO_Id 

FROM projects p, developer d 

WHERE p.PRO_Name LIKE '%Navin Enclave\\\\''s%' 

  AND d.DEV_Name LIKE '%Navin\\\\''s%'  //will in turn fetch Navin\'s group of Companies

  AND p.DEV_Id=d.DEV_Id 
LIMIT 1
```

Refer: [How to search for slash (\) in MySQL? and why escaping (\) not required for where (=) but for Like is required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926386/how-to-search-for-slash-in-mysql-and-why-escaping-not-required-for-wher)